# Rest assured vs Http client for Api testing?

Tags: rest-api, rest-assured, http

Which approach or should I say framework is better and which are let say 3 facts you should consider when making final decision?

Comment: Rest assured is a wrapper around Apache  HTTP client that makes writing tests easier for the price of flexibility. I would start with the Simpler one, i.e. RESTassured.

Answer (score 2):

> Which approach or should I say framework is better?

I don't think you can compare them just like that when you don't mention any context, any goals you might have, what you want to achieve with the tool, how big your project is, who is on the team, and many more.

> Which are let say 3 facts you should consider when making final decision?

Some things I'd consider:

- who will participate in the project, what are their (including mine) skills (can they handle the tool, if not, will there be some time for learning?)
- how big the project is - http clients are great for exploratory testing and tend to be a bit clumsy when it comes to managing many endpoints, a lot of test data, or when you want to reuse some parts (code)
- what intergations we need - how well the tool supports CI/CD pipelines, reporting, ...
- how easy it will be for someone completely new to take over - it's easier to start working with a http client than learn to code and then use a library like Rest-assured

The best setup is when you have enough space to fail. If you're not under a lot of pressure, pick one of the two, start using it and if it doesn't prove efficient on the project, change it. Yes, there'll be some rework, but you have to learn somehow, don't you?

Comment: Let exclude people knowlage, team knows booth tehnologies since they are not complicated. ... And let say project can be small but can be big, we have differet projects, but assume we want to use same technology.  Thank you for your answer it has good points.

Comment: Re: "http clients are great for exploratory testing". It really depends what you mean by HTTP client. [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/)? [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)? [curl command line tool](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) ? The first is definitely not the best for exporation, the latter two are definitely easier to explore APIs.

Comment: Yes, http client can mean many different tools. I had an image of something like Postman in mind.